# White Screen of Death--HTML?

Tags: javascript, screen, wsod

I'm noticing sometimes when I load my site (and when doing pingdom tests, etc) that the site just hangs and turns white, but as soon as you "refresh" the page everything loads properly.

I don't really know where to start. When I run waterfall reports from https://www.dotcom-tools.com/ a majority of the locations load perfectly fine, but 4 or 5 each time load in 50 seconds.

www.rubytuesdaybenefits.com/ft

Any ideas?!

Comment: I should note this is usually only for the first-time visit. Whenever I go back and visit the site it is fine (assuming it all caches)

Comment: Pull out the Chrome networking console and make sure all your assets are loading in good time.

Comment: Again, 90% of the time it loads in under 3 seconds. But just those few times it hangs and hangs. Could this just be a server issue?

Comment: Do you know which resource(s) are hanging?  Is it a CDN-hosted or self-hosted resource?  Is it an image, a script, video? etc...
It could be a server issue.

Comment: So I just cleared cache and tried it again, jquery-ui.css just "pending" forever and then I refreshed and it loaded fine.

Comment: I would check down that path.  If you host that file try isolating it (curl, browser, etc) to see what your results are there.  Check for status codes for hints.  If you have access to the server logs check there for any abnormalities.  I've had permission issues only show up in logs on some poorly configured client servers.  I'm sorry I can't be more specific.  There are still a lot of possible causes.